# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) on routing

Tags: express, routes, ejs

I am trying to route in my project. I want that on clicking connect button the rooms page should get rendered. Home page is working fine but as soon I as click connect it shows **Cannot GET /rooms/0b2636b5-c254-47f4-ade8-9e6b745a96d1**.The code works fine when instead of routing to rooms it is on root url.
I am new to web development and I tried reading other questions on similar problem but couldn't understand. 
**Server side(Server.js):**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const server = require('http').Server(app);
    const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid');
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);
    const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');
    const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
      debug: true
    });
    app.use('/peerjs', peerServer);
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render('home');
    })
    app.get('/rooms', (req, res) => {
        res.redirect(`/rooms/${uuidV4()}`);
      })
    
    app.get('/rooms:room', (req, res) => {
        res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
    })
    server.listen(3000);
```

**Client Side(script.js)**

```
const socket = io('/rooms');

const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid');
var peer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: '/peerjs',
  host: '/rooms',
  port: '3000'
})
```

**Navigation bar on home.ejs**

```
 <nav class="nav">
 <li class="nav-link">
 <a href="/rooms">Connect</a>
 </nav>
```

**room.ejs**

```
 <script>
        const ROOM_ID = "<%=roomId%>"
 </script>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer ></script>
 <script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

**Structure of file**

public
-script.js
views
-home.ejs
-room.ejs
server.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close to it, just 1 mistake in this block:

```
   app.get('/rooms:room', (req, res) => {
        res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
    })
```

It should be:

```
   app.get('/rooms/:room', (req, res) => {
        res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
    })
```

Express documentation page [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) in case you need it (section **Route parameters**).